# Should Message Listeners be in System Layer in Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mulesoft

I am adding a new flow to my Mulesoft application whose source/starting point is a SalesForce connector that listens to SF Platform events.

I am trying to understand which layer should this message listener be in

The confusion is that,

1. I think as a connector to pull SF data, this listener should be in the system layer
2. On the other hand, should flows be started in the system layer; and then they should call process layer for processing? Shouldn't communication start from experience, then come to process and then system layer ?

TIA

Comment: This question is related to MuleSoft API-led methodology and not to products/technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WjfkyL6OhA : at 5 min 15 seconds

says listeners should be in experience layer

Answer (score 0):

"System" layer describes APIs, not applications.  The listener you're describing is a mule application event source, not an API.

Perhaps you have created an [event driven API](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/news/anypoint-platform/event-driven-architecture-asyncapi/) whose client is your salesforce platform... the consumer is the publisher of the platform events. That consumer needs to know what the events need to look like so they can publish them to your integration layer.

In this case, I'd describe that as an experience API, since the consumer is external to your integrations.